# How to install OpenFlipper on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: qt, qt5, ubuntu-18.04

I am desperately trying to install Openflipper...

At the first time I tried to install OpenFlipper-Free like so https://www.graphics.rwth-aachen.de/media/openflipper_static/Daily-Builds/Doc/Free/Developer/buildingOpenFlipper.html. When I run `make`, I got this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmstL.png).

I looked through the [logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpVPm.png)(it's saying 5.9.5 is too high but I printed the used version underneath and it's actually too low) and documentation and I found that my QT5.9.5 was too old. I need at least 5.11.0.

So I installed Qt5.12.0 like so: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/481063/ubuntu-18-04-1-lts-x64-how-to-update-qt-5-10-from-qt-5-9-5

Now OpenFlipper compiled successfully. But when I run it and try to load a file, it crashs with this output

[image]:

I also tried to install older versions of Openflipper, but they also failed to compile, because Qt5.9.5 is too high for those versions.

I checked my Qt installations with `qmake -v` and `qtchooser -print-env` and it all looked fine.
I also looked through the Openflipper gitlab repo to find some advices but I couldn't find anything.

So now I am somehow stuck and I don't know what I do wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but I updated Ubuntu to 20.04 and now ObenFlipper works.